# Pyspark: TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref.ReferenceType

Tags: dataframe, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

TypeError: unfunc 'insane' not supported for the input types, and the input could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Hi,
I’m a beginner in Pyspark.
I am writing a function in Pyspark to read values and do some calculations in each row using numpy and metpy libraries.

I have a spark dataframe with multiple arrays in single column. I want to do some calculations on array column and add results in new column.

Example of my dataframe (sample only)

```
| array_col     | result|
| --------      | ------|
|[[2,4],[3,1,6]]|   2   |
|[[6,1],[1,8,7]]|  15   |
```

```
#My function is
import numpy as np
import metpy
def my_fun(data):
     print(data[0])
     print (type(data[0]))
     if (np.isnan[data[1]).any()):
         return np.nan
     else:
         #do some calculations with metpy, np libraries
         return lit(result)

df = df.withColumn(“result”, my_fun(df.array_col))`
```

```
output with error at "if (np.isnan[data[1]).any()):"
Column<'array_col[0]>
<class 'pts-ark.sql.column.Column'>
TypeError: unfunc 'insane' not supported for the input types, and the input could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I know the datatype passed in np.isnan is not an array. It is dataframe column.

If I simply return data[0] from my function without any calculations, I am getting following results for each rows. So I was expecting this should run for my code using other libraries

```
| array_col     | result|
| --------      | ------|
|[[2,4],[3,1,6]]| [2,4] |
|[[6,1],[1,8,7]]| [6,1] |
```

I tried rdd and looping through each rows in my data frame with same function, I am getting expected results but this is very time consuming because I have more than 3000000 rows in my dataframe and need to run the same code on 900 more dataframes. I am getting better results in pandas dataframe compared to spark dataframe for looping through each rows.

is there any way to execute code only withColumn function or select or sql to achieve the results. Basically I want to avoid UDF and I do not want to loop through each rows in the spark dataframe.

Thank You!!!

**Update** I have added a UDF and I am getting pickling error.

```
#My function is
    import numpy as np
    import metpy
    def my_fun(data):
         print(data[0])
         print (type(data[0]))
         if (np.isnan[data[1]).any()):
             return np.nan
         else:
             #do some calculations with metpy, np libraries
             return lit(result)
    
    myudffun = udf(lambda x: my_fun(x))
    
    df = df.withColumn(“result”, myudffun(df.array_col))`
```

got the following error

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)  File
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py:528, in
> CloudPickleSerializer.dumps(self, obj)  527 try:  --> 528 return
> cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)  529 except
> pickle.PickleError:  File
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py:73,
> in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)  70 cp = CloudPickler(  71
> file, protocol=protocol, buffer_callback=buffer_callback  72 )  --->
> 73 cp.dump(obj)  74 return file.getvalue()  File
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py:632,
> in CloudPickler.dump(self, obj)  631 try:  --> 632 return
> Pickler.dump(self, obj)  633 except RuntimeError as e:  TypeError:
> cannot pickle 'weakref.ReferenceType' object

any suggestion on this please

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible to avoid using a udf unless whatever operation you're performing in the metpy or numpy library can also be done with spark functions

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Spark do not support same functions as numpy and metpy.

Comment: then as far as i know, you probably cannot avoid using a `udf`